# How can I tell what server I am on?

Tags: dota-2

So when you queue up, you can select what servers you'd like to search in.  I keep ending up playing with people who just don't speak english, which takes away from the game a lot.

It would help if I could see which server I'm on when I get placed with them, so that I can remove that server.

Is there a way to see what server you are on, after queuing for multiple?

Comment: I hate this too, you should be able to select languages instead of location. I rather wait 10 minutes for a team that speaks English then just a minute or two and stuck with Russians or lazy west European people.

Comment: You can set languages! that's why this already shouldn't be a problem =(

Comment: What? I did not double check this but i am pretty sure i was only able to set a region.

Comment: Just checked and you are right, region and language preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way i guess you can tell which server you played on is by using `dotabuff.com`. Just replace your game ID after matches/.

Here is an example:
http://dotabuff.com/matches/364337412

Which gives these details:

Lobby Type: Normal Matchmaking

Game Mode: All Pick

**Region: South Korea** <<- Which you interested in

Duration: 39:13

Played: 22 hours ago

Hope that helps

Comment: He wants to determine the server on which he's playing right after the game loads up i guess.

Comment: @Edeph I'm afraid that isn't possible. He mentions "so that I can remove that server." it can't be helped anyway because he is already in the game. This is one way after the game where he'll be able to at least get an idea of the server so he can avoid it the next time.

Comment: I know but it's always good to pick the servers that are close to your location. Indeed it can't be possible to find out ingame, but limiting the selections from the start can be a good choice.

Comment: @Edeph, Agreed! But there is an option for language selection which no one tends to select. I'm guessing even the non English speakers have it set to English.

Comment: this is actually really helpful, I already use dotabuff to check stats after games.  I'll just have to check soon enough afterwards to remember if they didn't speak english.

Answer (score 3):

You can open the console and then type "status"

This will give you the IP of the server you're connected to, which you can then use with various sites on the internet to find the actual physical location of the server.

For example, use http://www.iplocation.net/

Comment: You also have the ip from all server here http://thebinaryrealm.blogspot.in/2013/10/list-of-ip-addresses-of-all-dota2.html

Comment: When you use the `status` command the server name will have the region in it.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you select a server (US W/E, South Africa, Europe W/E, SE Asia etc) and you have only 1 server selected, you will play on this server no matter how long it takes to find a game. If you have multiple server selected, the following commands (from console) may be helpful :

- sv_region (The region of the world to report this server in)
- sv_logfile (Log server information in the log file.)

I am not 100% sure at the moment those will give you the information you need however it's worth a try

Comment: Can we get a check if this actually tells whatregion the server belongs to ? I'm unable to check atm.